# Invalid binding path 'MyStatic' : Property 'MyStatic' can't be found on type 'CreatePage'

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

So I've been looking for the wright solution for my problem. It seems I'm not able to bind to a observableCollection that is located in my models folder. I am able to add items in it and in a later stadium retrieve these with some C# Code. BUT I just can't seem to bind to the items from a page I named CreatePage.

I keep getting this message: Invalid binding path 'Questionlist' : Property 'Questionlist' can't be found on type 'CreatePage'.

Class with the observableCollection:

```
public partial class MyStatic
{
        static MyStatic()
        {
            Questionlist = new ObservableCollection<QuestionList>();            
        }
        public static ObservableCollection<QuestionList> Questionlist;
    }
public class QuestionList
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string Delete { get; set; }
    public string Correct { get; set; }
    public string Wrong { get; set; }
    public string UserAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="4"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  Margin="20,10"
                  MaxWidth="650">
        <RelativePanel>
            <ListView Name="Questionviewlist"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind Questionlist}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:QuestionList">
                        <TextBlock Name="Questionview"
                                   Text="{x:Bind Question}"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                   FontFamily="Arial Rounded MT Bold"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="Brown"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <ListView Name="Answerviewlist"
                      RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind Questionlist}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:QuestionList">
                        <TextBlock Name="Answerview"
                           Text="{x:Bind Answer}"
                                   FontFamily="Arial Rounded MT Bold"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   Foreground="Brown"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <ListView Name="Deleteviewlist"
                      RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind Questionlist}"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                      ItemClick="Deleteviewlist_ItemClick">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:QuestionList">
                        <TextBlock Name="Deleteview"
                                   Text="{x:Bind Delete}"
                                   TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                   Foreground="#FFB57C"
                                   FontStyle="Italic"
                                   FontFamily="Arial Rounded MT Bold"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </RelativePanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: check your data context on that object where you are getting that error. Also post the complete error message. Look at the output window when you build.

Comment: @Versatile the thing is that once i move the observableCollection to the CreatedPage codebehind it does bind. Because I want to use the collection on different pages I dont want to put there. Is there a way to change the itemsource scope from CreatedPage to the class in the model folder? In the output window I do see Question, Answer and Delete but keep getting the error: Invalid binding path 'MyStatic' : Property 'MyStatic' can't be found on type 'CreatePage'

Comment: yes you can create a object in xaml and bind to that. Everytime, update that same object and you can have your changes reflected in the UI

Comment: @BeeJeeP You need to make yourself familiar with basic concepts of data binding, especially how to specify the source object of a binding. To make things complicated, there are also some differences between `{Binding}` and `{x:Bind}`. I'd suggest you start reading here: [Data binding overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart).

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the comment! I'll start reading :)

Comment: Thanks guy! I got the solution!

Comment: what is the solution ? its not obvious. also someone marked questions as duplicated. but didn't refer the link.